# System.out.print .. printing not in order

Tags: java

I'm using  `System.out.print` to print an `arrayList (cl)`, The code looks like this:

```
System.out.print("Returning  \n");
for(int i = 0 ; i <cl.size(); i++){
    if(i+1 == cl.size())
        System.out.print(cl.get(i));
    else
        System.out.print(cl.get(i)+" ,");
}
```

**The output should look like:**

Returning 1,2,3....

**but it shows up like this:**

0 ,5 ,6 Returning

**Edit:** The problem is not in the order of the elements, but in "Returning" position.

I'm using Windows 8 as an operations system and NetBeans as IDE.
Why?!

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. Also try just printing out `cl` to look at the contents of the list.

Comment: I don't know what you mean - if you just write `System.out.println(cl);` what do you get? Again, a short but complete program would help us to help you quicker.

Comment: System.out.print(cl.get(i)); I'm getthing the i-th element of cl

Comment: Ah, I see - so it's not the order of the *elements* which is a problem, just that `Returning` comes first, right? Which operating system are you using? (The `\n` could be causing issues...) And how are you running the code? Once again, a short but complete program demonstrating the problem - with more context about how you're running it - would really help.

Comment: I'm using Windows 8 and NetBeans

Comment: your code looks fine, are you sure your array looks like you expected? try debug it, and check are you really getting what you expect

Comment: What happens if you run the program from the command line? (I'm running out of time to help you for now, and the continued lack of a short but complete program demonstrating the problem isn't helpful.)

Comment: I'm really not getting your point about complete program .. I'm only printing a list that is filled by another method.

Comment: @Lisa: it's plain English. Write a complete program, that we can copy and paste to reproduce the problem. It should start with the `package` statement, and end with the closing curly brace of the class. And it should have a main method. The class should compile, and it should reproduce the problem you're facing.

Comment: Your code is correct and outputs the array content as expected, I have just tested.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have an output like Returning 1,2,3.... 
First the ArrayList CL should contains numbers 1,2... and so on
Second try to use System.out.println("Returning   ");